# method delay and fadeTo not working in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This function hSlider() starts from  $(document).ready(function () {... hSlider(); ...
It displays lines in time sequence, quite simple. This is working perfect in Chrome and IE but does not work in FF. Can anybody explain it ?

---

```
function hSlider() {
         $('#head-slider ul>li').each(function(i) {
                sthis = this;
    $(sthis).delay(1000*i).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    });
};

<html>
 <div id="head-slider"> 
         <ul>
          <li>first lines</li>                         
          <li>second line</li>                            
          <li>third line</li>
          </ul>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Works for me in last version of Firefox (win7). http://jsfiddle.net/nefg2kru/1/

Comment: its true. I've used ff debager and when I set a breakpoint on that function it displays OK when BP is off nothing what's the hell ? Seems that I have to look somewhere else not just this function.